# make: execute an action for each prerequisite

Tags: makefile

I would like to build a rule like this one in my Makefile:

```
log: test_A test_B
    ./test_A >> $@
    ./test_B >> $@
```

but `test_A` and `test_B` are part of a `$(TESTS)` variable.

So, is it possible to do an action (here: call the program) for each prerequisite in GNU/make?

Note: [How do I make a makefile rule execute its prerequisites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518531/how-do-i-make-a-makefile-rule-execute-its-prerequisites) does not completely solve this problem, as the target `log` is required (`make log`).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Essentially you want to loop over the prerequisites.  The obvious way to do this is to punt to the shell:

```
log: test_A test_B
        for f in $^; do ./$$f; done
```

Or you could write the loop as a GNU Make `foreach` loop, though you have to be careful that the commands that result from the body of the loop appear on separate lines (via `define`) or are terminated with a shell terminator (i.e., a semi-colon, which is easier):

```
log: test_A test_B
        $(foreach f,$^,./$(f);)
```

Finally, in this case you could write it more succinctly and more obscurely as a pattern substitution on each item to be looped over:

```
log: test_A test_B
        $(patsubst %,./%;,$^)
```

(I'm sure you can add the output redirection and `$(TESTS)` variable as appropriate.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it confirms what I ended up with:

`$(foreach test, $^, $(shell ./$(test) >> $@))`

Comment: If that's the commands for your _log_ rule, then `$(shell ...)` is kind of subverting things: the commands for the rule will be empty, and the `test_?` executions will happen as a byproduct of figuring out the commands (rather than happening by executing the commands).  Philosophically wrong, and -- more practically -- impossible to extend to catch the failure of one of your `test_?` scripts.  (But nonetheless it would appear that you want to mark this answer as accepted...)

Comment: Wont this loop twice, once for test_A and once for  test_B? I have a similar issue and make is behaving very strangely.