# How to copy all prerequisites to a certain folder in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, for-loop, makefile

I want to copy all prerequisites into a folder to then process them there. I have tried a shell for loop, but the syntax seems to be different

```
for f in $^; do cp $f some/folder/; done
```

I also tried the foreach loop from GNU make

```
$(foreach f,$^,cp $f some/folder/)
```

I have found this explanation, but I don't really understand it

[make: execute an action for each prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918511/make-execute-an-action-for-each-prerequisite)

Here is my recipe

```
CURRENT := $(PWD)
IMAGE_TREE_SOURCE := ./device/layer/kernelFitImage.its
FIT_PREREQUISITES := $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/$(TARGET_KERNEL_ARCH)/boot/Image \
                     $(PRODUCT_OUT)/ramdisk-recovery.img \
                     $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/$(TARGET_KERNEL_ARCH)/boot/dts/freescale/imx8mm-gpv-distec.dtb \
                     $(IMAGE_TREE_SOURCE)
FIT_IMAGE_TARGET := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot/fitImage
$(FIT_IMAGE_TARGET): $(FIT_PREREQUISITES)
    echo "Creating FIT image"
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    # for f in $^; do $$f $(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot; done
    cd $(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot
    cp $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/$(TARGET_KERNEL_ARCH)/boot/Image .
    cp $(PRODUCT_OUT)/ramdisk-recovery.img .
    cp $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/$(TARGET_KERNEL_ARCH)/boot/dts/freescale/imx8mm-gpv-distec.dtb .
    cp $(IMAGE_TREE_SOURCE) .
    mkimage -f kernelFitImage.its $@
    rm ./Image 
    rm ./ramdisk-recovery.img
    rm ./imx8mm-gpv-distec.dtb
    rm ./kernelFitImage.its
    cd $(CURRENT)
```

I am trying to substitute all the copy statements to clean this recipe up a bit.

Comment: You should provide the entire rule in your question, not just a single line.  You should also include error messages, etc. you get (cut and paste the text, not paraphrased, not an attached or linked image).  Makefiles are line-oriented and context-sensitive so where that line is placed makes all the difference in answering questions.

Comment: Assuming that the first try you show above appears properly in a recipe for a rule, the problem is simply that you forgot to escape the shell variable `$f`.  Since you want the shell to see the `$`, you have to escape it from make by writing `$$f` instead.

Comment: I tried that with the double $$. It also seemed to fail. I added the whole recipe now. People are really picky here. Sometimes I write too much and other times too little. :)

Comment: Before I just copied every single prerequisite and that worked just fine.

Comment: "It also seemed to fail" is not a problem we can help with.  Please see my comments above about including error messages etc.  No one will complain about including necessary information.  People may complain about including a ton of _unnecessary_ information.  For example, all your source code, or your entire makefile, or the entire output of your build.  But no one will complain if you include the makefile rule that doesn't work, or the specific lines of code that don't compile, or a representative sample of the error messages you receive and the command line that generated them.

Comment: Well mkimage command doesn't find the prerequisites. 

``FATAL ERROR: Couldn't open "kernelFitImage.its": No such file or directory``

So someting is wrong about the for loop that copies the files. I just need a for loop that copies all prerequisites the current directory by using a dot . or some other directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop; why can't you just use `cp $^ $(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot` ?  However, the for loop DOES work.  If you go look in the directory after the failure, don't you see the files you copied there?  If something is failing you'll have to look for some other problem.

I will point out that unless you're setting oneshell in your makefile, this can't work:

```
cd $(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot
cp $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/$(TARGET_KERNEL_ARCH)/boot/Image .
 ...
```

Every individual logical line in a recipe is run in a *separate shell*.  So after each line is complete, the shell exits (so make knows what its exit code is and whether it failed or not).  When that happens all context local to the shell which includes environment variables *and the working directory*, are thrown away.

So, the `cd ...` line above is a no-op: it will change to the directory in a subshell, then the subshell exits and you're back where you started.  The next shell will still be in the original directory.

You have to turn this into a single logical line, by adding semicolons and backslashes:

```
cd $(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot; \
cp $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/$(TARGET_KERNEL_ARCH)/boot/Image .; \
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Makefiles are really weird, but I guess for a reason. I will try this out tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Solved. :)  Thank you again for taking the time to explain this to me!